# Adding new extension to CKAN

Tags: ckan

I want to add extension found in giuhub (https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-pages) to ckan deployment (i've installed the package deployment of ckan)

can anyone instruct me how to install this extension ?

Thanks
Arik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [documentation about installing extensions](http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.3/extensions/tutorial.html#installing-the-extension).

It basically boils down to these commands:

```bash
. /usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/activate # activate the virtualenv
cd /usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-pages
python setup.py develop
```

Then you need add the `pages` to the `ckan.plugins` in your ini file:

```bash
ckan.plugins = stats text_view recline_view pages
```